# Error when running Python3 command in Ubuntu server?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run a python command in Ubuntu server by using command ($ python3 es7.py). 
But got the error (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'confluent_kafka').

My es7.py script

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import json
import requests
import time
p = Producer({"bootstrap_servers": "localhost:9092"})
while True:
    response1 = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=jaipur&appid=**")
    p.produce('weather', key='jaipur', value=response1.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have the necessary dependency (confluent_kafka) installed on the ubuntu server. Install it first.

You can install it with:

```
pip install confluent-kafka
```

As described [here](https://pypi.org/project/confluent-kafka/).